# Jest RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when trying to import a dependency that has been mocked

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm mocking `mssql`, and to do so I placed a file called `mssql.js` in my `__mocks__` folder in the root directory (next to `node_modules/`).

Now I need to import mssql in my tests in order to change one of the mocked functions, like so:

```js
const sql = require("mssql");
sql.connect = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
    query: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
        recordset: [0],
        recordsets: [0, 0],
    }),
    close: jest.fn()
})
```

This is throwing the following error in the `__mocks__/mssql.js` file:

```
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

    > 1 | const sql = require("mssql");
        |                         
      2 | jest.mock("mssql");
      3 |
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but may have the files reversed. Something like this should work, according to the [Jest manual mock docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks):

`__mocks__/mssql.js`:

```
const sql = jest.createMockFromModule("mssql");
sql.connect = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
    query: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
        recordset: [0],
        recordsets: [0, 0],
    }),
    close: jest.fn()
})
module.exports = sql;
```

In your test file, `mssql` should now use the mock `connect` function in your manual mock.

`tests/foo.test.js`:

```
jest.mock("mssql");

it('should ...', () => {
  ...
});
```